# How to re size the window in C

Tags: fullscreen

Hey I'm learning C and we have done all our coding in Visual studio. All our programs have been created and outputted into a command prompt type window. You can't make this window full screen or anything. All you can do is change how long it is vertical wise. Is there a certain code I can use in my program to change the size of the window and make it static?

If the code for it is too long to type, a link to a website with a tutorial for it would be helpful. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a set of Console functions.  See the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It looks to me like you need to determine the maximum size of console using [GetLargestConsoleWindowSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then set that size using [SetConsoleWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
This helps. Didn't know you could do any of this.